# How to disable BottomSheetScaffold Bounce/Jump effect when sheet is full expanded

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am using BottomSheetScaffold in one of my projects and I just put some content in the bottom sheet but when I swipe up on the expanded sheet, the sheet jumps/bounces, revealing the content of background.

Is there a way to remove this effect In BottomSheetScaffold? When it is expanded, swipe should not bounce the bottom sheet

A visual representation is attached below:

[image]

Code in question (please ignore custom theme values) :

```
val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
var currentSheetStat by remember { mutableStateOf(SheetContent.BookingRide) }
var sheetPeekHeight by remember {
    mutableStateOf(420.dp)
}
BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    sheetPeekHeight = sheetPeekHeight,
    sheetShadowElevation = 0.dp,
    sheetTonalElevation = 0.dp,
    containerColor = Color.Transparent,
    sheetContent = {

        Column {
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .padding(
                        start = BnTheme.gaps.component,
                        end = BnTheme.gaps.component,
                        bottom = BnTheme.gaps.component
                    )
                    .fillMaxWidth())
            {
                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    if(currentSheetStat == SheetContent.RideStarted) {
                        BnPebbleMedium(pebbleText = stringResource(id = commonR.string.sos),
                            hasLeadingIcon = true, leadingIcon = painterResource(id = commonR.drawable.ic_alert_badge),
                            leadingIconTint = BnTheme.colors.error, pebbleTextColor = BnTheme.colors.error,
                            pebbleContainer = BnTheme.colors.surfaceContainer)
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                    Card(
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(100),
                        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                            containerColor = BnTheme.colors.surfaceContainer
                        ),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(48.dp)
                    ) {
                        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = commonR.drawable.ic_locate),
                                contentDescription = null, Modifier.size(24.dp),
                                tint = shades_dark_blue_0
                            )
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

            Card(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.Transparent),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = BnTheme.cornerRadius.crL, topEnd = BnTheme.cornerRadius.crL),
                colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                    containerColor = BnTheme.colors.surfaceContainer
                ),
                elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 2.dp)
            ) {

                AnimatedContent(
                    targetState = currentSheetStat,
                    label = "",
                ) {
                    Crossfade(targetState = it, label = "bottom sheet animation") {
                        when(it) {
                            SheetContent.BookingRide ->  {
                               //not important
                            }
                            SheetContent.ConfirmPickupLocation -> {
                                //not important
                            }
                            SheetContent.SendingRequest -> {
                                sheetPeekHeight = 220.dp
                                SheetContentSendingRequest{
                                    currentSheetStat = SheetContent.NavigatorArrival
                                }
                            }
                            SheetContent.NavigatorArrival -> {
                                // not important
                            }
                            SheetContent.RideStarted -> {
                                //not important
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    },
    sheetContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
    sheetDragHandle = {
        HorizontalDivider(thickness = 0.dp,
            color = Color.Transparent)
    }
    ) {

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        ScreenContent() // the background map implementation
    }
}
```

And this is the Sheet content

```
@Composable
fun SheetContentSendingRequest( onRideRequestSent : () -> Unit ) {
Column(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .padding(
        horizontal = BnTheme.gaps.component,
        vertical = BnTheme.gaps.element
    ))
{

    SheetDragHandle()

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(BnTheme.gaps.component))

    Column (
        Modifier
            .padding(vertical = BnTheme.gaps.element)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally){
        BnText(
            text = stringResource(id = commonR.string.sent_ride_request),
            style = BnTheme.typography.titleSmallSemiBold,
            color = BnTheme.colors.bodyPrimary
        )

        Row {
            Row {
                BnText(
                    text = stringResource(commonR.string.you_will_reach_destination_by),
                    style = BnTheme.typography.bodyMediumMedium,
                    color = BnTheme.colors.bodySecondary
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(BnTheme.gaps.mini))

                BnText(
                    text = "11:11 AM",
                    style = BnTheme.typography.bodyMediumMedium,
                    color = BnTheme.colors.link
                )
            }
        }
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(BnTheme.gaps.component))

    Row {
        LinearProgressIndicator(
            progress = 1f,
            trackColor = BnTheme.colors.primaryButtonOff,
            color = BnTheme.colors.primaryButtonOn,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(horizontal = 12.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(100))
        )


        LinearProgressIndicator(
            progress = 0f,
            trackColor = BnTheme.colors.primaryButtonOff,
            color = BnTheme.colors.primaryButtonOn,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(horizontal = 12.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(100))


        )

        LinearProgressIndicator(
            progress = 0f,
            trackColor = BnTheme.colors.primaryButtonOff,
            color = BnTheme.colors.primaryButtonOn,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(horizontal = 12.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(100))

        )

        LinearProgressIndicator(
            progress = 0f,
            trackColor = BnTheme.colors.primaryButtonOff,
            color = BnTheme.colors.primaryButtonOn,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(horizontal = 12.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(100))


        )
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(BnTheme.gaps.component))

    Icon(painter = painterResource(id = commonR.drawable.vector_shared_ride), contentDescription = null,
        tint = Color.Unspecified, modifier = Modifier
            .height(124.dp)
            .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            .noRippleClickable { onRideRequestSent() })
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(BnTheme.gaps.component))


}
```

}

Comment: Can you please edit your post and include your `BottomSheetScaffold` code? It would make experimenting around easier.

Comment: If you don't need the user to swipe the sheet at all you could turn it off with the sheetSwipeEnabled = false parameter. Then you could hide and show the sheet with bottomSheetState.expand() and bottomSheetState.hide()

Comment: @Aron actually there are more sheets like this in the app and many of them swipe to show more content. So in those cases, can't disable the swipe controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not intended behavior, so you can consider opening an issue on the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) so that the Android Developer Team can take a look at this. I can however present you a workaround.

I found that the `sheetPeekHeight` parameter of the [`BottomSheetScaffold`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#BottomSheetScaffold(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.BottomSheetScaffoldState,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1)) Composable plays an important role. My guess is that you have set it to `0.dp`. If you set the `sheetPeekHeight` to `10.dp`, the BottomSheet will have a rectangular Composable with 10dp height at the bottom area behind the BottomSheet.

You can use this behavior to cover the Scaffold background when swiping up. Please update your Composable as follows:

```
val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
val bottomSheetState = scaffoldState.bottomSheetState  // just for convenience

BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    sheetPeekHeight = 
        if (bottomSheetState.currentValue == SheetValue.Expanded &&
            bottomSheetState.targetValue == SheetValue.Expanded) {
            50.dp
        } else {
            0.dp
        },
    sheetContent = {
        //...
    }
) {
    //...
}
```

With this code, when the BottomSheet is expanded, we temporarily set the `sheetPeekHeight` to 50dp to cover up the Scaffold background when swiping up.

Note however the limitation that when you positioned elements relatively in your Scaffold (for example by using a Column with `verticalArrangement`), these elements will move, as the size of the Scaffold content is temporarily decreased when the BottomSheet is expanded.

---

In your case, `sheetContainerColor = Color.Transparent` causes the problematic behavior. The only workaround that comes to my mind is to manually display a background overlay behind the BottomSheet. You can try it as follows:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    ScreenContent() // the background map implementation
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
           .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
           .fillMaxWidth()
           .height(sheetPeekHeight - 25.dp)
           .background(BnTheme.colors.surfaceContainer)
    )
}
```

However, your code is a little bit strange. To expand or collapse a BottomSheet, you should use

- [`scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/SheetState#expand())
- [`scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.partialExpand()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/SheetState#partialExpand())
- [`scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.hide()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/SheetState#hide())

instead of modifying the `sheetPeekHeight`. Also have a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/SheetState).

Comment: I tried adding the code you mentioned but it seems like the sheet is now completely hidden. Actually I have modified the sheet quiet a bit. I had to add a button which stays attached to sheet top so I made the sheet transparent, then added the column with button. Then used a card with sheet style to compansate for the transparent sheet.

I have added the code for reference if that helps. Please ignore theme styles there. We are using a custom theme in our app

Comment: Then `sheetContainerColor = Color.Transparent` is the actual problem. I edited my answer to propose a workaround.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The Color.Transparent for sheetContainerColor is indeed the problem. With this, it will be easier to apply a fix as you suggested. Thanks for the help!